# How to connect to Mariadb (mysql fork) database and retrieve some data within Fortran

Tags: mysql, fortran, fortran90

I am able to use Mysql Workbench to access and retrieve some data from a Mariadb database, save them on a text file and then load it in fortran. I have a fortran 95 numerical model and I would like to automatically retrieve data from a fortran subroutine and store it as fortran variables (I have to do it many times). Which one do you think is the best way to do this? Maybe by using some Fortran libraries? I only need to send some simple query such as:

```
 SELECT * FROM observed.temperature where ID_MISURA = 10210801
```

Comment: You can write a function in C with all the available libraries in C, and call the C function in fortran using the interoperabilities stuff.

Comment: To follow up on @innoSPG there is an example  [here](https://mariadb.org/fortran-and-mariadb/). Alternatively [flibs](http://flibs.sourceforge.net/) suggests it has some library routines for dealing with different database types.